# Yii2 ActiveDataProvider sort using count in relational

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

Yii2 ActiveDataProvider sort using count in relational ?

I've 3 tables, bellow :
[image: Table Schema]

And I displaying data from table inventory_device_type, here is the code :

Controller :

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers\inventory;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Action;

use app\models\tables\InventoryDeviceType;

class DeviceInventory extends Action
{
    public function run()
    {
        $model = new InventoryDeviceType();
        $dataProvider = $model->search(Yii::$app->request->post());

        return $this->controller->render('device-inventory',[
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            ]);
    }
}
```

Model :

```
<?php
namespace app\models\tables;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;

class InventoryDeviceType extends ActiveRecord
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'inventory_device_type';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name','id_device_vendor'],'required'],
            ['name','unique']
        ];
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id_device_vendor' => 'Device Vendor',
        ];
    }

    /** queries **/

    public function findData($id)
    {
        if(($data = self::findOne($id)) == null){
            throw new NotFoundHttpException;
        }else{
            return $data;
        }
    }

    public function getNormal()
    {
        return $this->getList()->where(['inventory_device_list.device_condition' => 'normal'])->count();
    }

    public function getBroken()
    {
        return $this->getList()->where(['inventory_device_list.device_condition' => 'broken'])->count();
    }

    public function getSold()
    {
        return $this->getList()->where(['inventory_device_list.device_condition' => 'sold'])->count();
    }

    public function getTotal()
    {
        return $this->getList()->where(['!=','inventory_device_list.device_condition',''])->count();
    }

    public static function getVendorList($sort=[])
    {
        return InventoryDeviceVendor::find()->orderBy($sort)->all();
    }

    public function search($params, $spesific=[],$sort=[])
    {
        $query = self::find();
        $query->where($spesific);

        $query->joinWith(['list']);

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
                'query' => $query,
                'sort' => ['defaultOrder' => $sort]
            ]);

        $dataProvider->sort->attributes['vendor_name'] = [
            'asc' => ['inventory_device_vendor.name' => SORT_ASC],
            'desc' => ['inventory_device_vendor.name' => SORT_DESC],
        ];

        /** sort on page device-inventory **/

        $dataProvider->sort->attributes['device_vendor'] = [
            'asc' => ['inventory_device_vendor.name' => SORT_ASC],
            'desc' => ['inventory_device_vendor.name' => SORT_DESC],
        ];

        /** sort on page device-inventory end **/

        return $dataProvider;
    }

    /** queries end **/

    /** relation **/

    public function getListLeft()
    {
        return InventoryDeviceList::find();
    }

    public function getList()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(InventoryDeviceList::className(),['id_device_type' => 'id']);
    }

    public function getVendorLeft()
    {
        return InventoryDeviceVendor::find();
    }

    public function getVendor()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(InventoryDeviceVendor::className(),['id' => 'id_device_vendor']);
    }

    /** relation end **/



}
```

and here is the view :

```
<?= 

            GridView::widget([
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                'layout' => '<div class="table-responsive">{items}</div> {summary} {pager}',
                'columns' => [
                    [
                        'class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn',
                        'headerOptions' => ['width' => 50]
                    ],
                    'name',
                    [
                        'attribute' => 'device_vendor',
                        'class' => 'yii\grid\DataColumn',
                        'value' => function($data){
                            return $data->vendor->name;
                        }
                    ],
                    [
                        'attribute' => 'normal',
                        'class' => 'yii\grid\DataColumn',
                        'format' => 'html',
                        'value' => function($data){
                            return Html::a($data->getNormal(),'#',['class' => 'label label-success']);
                        },
                    ],
                    [
                        'attribute' => 'sold',
                        'class' => 'yii\grid\DataColumn',
                        'format' => 'html',
                        'value' => function($data){
                            return Html::a($data->getSold(),'#',['class' => 'label label-warning']);
                        },
                    ],
                    [
                        'attribute' => 'broken',
                        'class' => 'yii\grid\DataColumn',
                        'format' => 'html',
                        'value' => function($data){
                            return Html::a($data->getBroken(),'#',['class' => 'label label-danger']);
                        },
                    ],
                    [
                        'attribute' => 'Total',
                        'class' => 'yii\grid\DataColumn',
                        'format' => 'html',
                        'value' => function($data){
                            return Html::a($data->getTotal(),'#',['class' => 'label label-primary']);
                        },
                    ],

                ],
                ]);

                ?>
```

and how to sort it, like normal, broken, and, sold ?
here is : the result view :
[image]

the header normal, sold, broke and all not sortable, i can sort by relation if not using count like this code (like Device Vendor):

```
$dataProvider->sort->attributes['device_vendor'] = [
        'asc' => ['inventory_device_vendor.name' => SORT_ASC],
        'desc' => ['inventory_device_vendor.name' => SORT_DESC],
    ];
```

Comment: Seems all rights .. what's the problem? error.. wrong result?.. please explain what's wrong..

Comment: the header normal, sold, broke and all not sortable, i can sort by relation if not using count.
I've updated the question detail.